# Should I use a 3rd party stock charting java library or not?

Tags: java, swing, graph, charts, jfreechart

I am creating a project for my studies which is based upon a trading system.
This trading system is using some moving averages to decide when to buy or sell a stock.
The language that I will use is java.
My question is whether I should use a 3rd party library (like JFreeChart) or should I try to build the whole application on my own (I have some java swing experience)?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you confident with your self to build a new one? Is this project is long-term project or short-term? If you don't have time to build a new one, than use the existing one...

Comment: The system is very simple, just some moving averages (one of them is fluctuating around a zero line), so I need three panes (price chart, moving averages, volume).

Comment: I think you should take the challenge, the advantage with custom library is all the method and class that you declared is definitely will be use :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If there is something which already does what you need, you should really use that in the first place.

Creating your own, is usually not advisable since using 3rd party applications will mean that you will be using something which is already tested and has lots of more features.

Using a 3rd party API will save you time, time which you can than invest into other aspects of your project (communities always tend to make life simpler).

A few more points I thought I should mention is that although developing everything yourself is usually a great (if not the best) way of learning things, I think that employers tend to prefer it when people are already familiar with certain 3rd party popular API's.

Comment: Some comments after trying JFreeChart : this tool is amazing and I am very pleased now that I am using it and considering the time I can save using this tool.I even bought the manual which is very detailed and well-written.Well done to the authors of this beautiful piece of software!

Comment: @skiabox: Glad it is working for you. Hold on tight to that manual because for most open source projects, good documentation is hard to come by ;)

Comment: I can understand now that I am using it why it is the de facto standard.Thank you all for your advice!

Answer (score 4):

If the licenses are compatible (for instance JFreeChart is LGPL, so you can use it without opening your source code), and the library does what you need, why would you reinvent the wheel?

Using a library that is already tested and developed by many people can save you a lot of time, and if you need something different or a bug fixed, you can always fix it yourself and commit it so the rest of the community can also benefit.

Answer (score 3):

If I were you I would befriend `JFreeChart`. It is a *de facto* standard for Swing plotting/charting (at least in the free world). It has some quirks and needs some hacking to get your result from time to time. But it is well tested, the limitations are well known, there is a [community](http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewforum.php?f=3) of users with experience that can help you with the problems.

I would rather not reinvent the wheel, unless I needed a very specific wheel...

Answer (score 2):

It depends how much time you have and what you want to achieve, if you create your own charting it would be great experience, but if you are looking towards building your career in finance domain then you would be better off looking at the [pricing models](http://quantlib.org/index.shtml).

Also there are many matured solutions to get your charting requirement done, you can just use them so as to save time and definitely you can learn a lot by looking at some great Open Source code.